# How can I protect MP4 Videos (Token, IP etc.)

Tags: php, session, video

I don't want to view .mp4 videos directly.

There are many sources on the Internet, but most of them are out of date or did not know if it was right for me.

So I wanted to consult you.

Let's say I have videos on my server.

Example video URL:

http://cdn.sitename.com/video15.mp4

I don't want to share this directly as http://cdn.sitename.com/video15.mp4"> .

In this way, the video can be accessed directly.

The .mp4 link between the source tags must be a random URL. This url must be opened according to the user's session. The URL created for this User should not work on anyone else and access the original.mp4 source.

them

Can I show a URL like to create a custom for each user?

The original .mp4 file will be included in the PHP page, but it will reflect a random mp4 to the user in the source code.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no way of actually hiding video url if it's not actually hosted on your site. I also found [This Post](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-embed-a-youtube-video-in-my-website-without-revealing-its-actual-url) which also states the same

Comment: Thanks. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/695141/protecting-videos-from-being-stolen-in-browser In fact, this works better for me.

How can I make this safer ..

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, if the video is available to played by a user you can't stop them downloading it and sharing it, just in case this is what you are trying to avoid.

To deal with this the usual approach is to encrypt the video and to either share the encryption key privately or to use a DRM system to securely provide the key to the end user.

If all you want to do is make it harder for random users to guess the URL there are several approaches you can use:

- Use signed URLs - here is an AWS example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html
- Obfuscating the URL - you need to be aware that this can be seen as security issue, depending on how you do it as the user may worry they don't know where the URL is going
- Session or token based authentication - this will allow you only make the page or asset available to authenticated users. There is a good summary of the difference here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/92123

Comment: nginx secure link